# How to add deep linking to my Android app?

Tags: deep-linking, deeplink

I have just followed the documentation on deep linking via https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html and in the end, any of my domain links I click refers me to the main activity on the app rather than opening the link to article I clicked on.

Do I create a different activity, or I need to configure the main activity?

I have little experience with Android app development, I'm only relying on tutorials and forums to help.

Comment: Does the example manifest on this page help? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I already came across this link too, I still wasn't able to get what I'm looking for.

Comment: android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity" As this one here, do I need to create a new activity for deep linking

Comment: It's been over a year since I've worked on Android, but from what it looks like the deep linking configuration is an extension of an intent filtering mechanism, which is an activity-level concern. Thus, I would imagine that for each screen you want to handle a different path, you would need a different activity. It would be helpful to see an example of the manifest that you are working with.

It's also important to distinguish if you're trying to create a deep link or app link as well. Maybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#the-difference